# Why does my logging library cause performance tests to run faster?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance

I have spent the past year developing a logging library in C++ with performance in mind. To evaluate performance I developed [a set of benchmarks](https://github.com/mattiasflodin/reckless/blob/de548af1f5ea9f716f76b691402b52107ef701e3/doc/performance.md) to compare my code with other libraries, including a base case that performs no logging at all.

In my last benchmark I measure the total running time of a CPU-intensive task while logging is active and when it is not. I can then compare the time to determine how much overhead my library has. This bar chart shows the difference compared to my non-logging base case.

[image: performance chart]

As you can see, my library ("reckless") adds *negative overhead* (unless all 4 CPU cores are busy). The program runs about half a second faster when logging is enabled than when it is disabled.

I know I should try to isolate this down to a simpler case rather than asking about a 4000-line program. But there are so many venues for what to remove, and without a hypothesis I will just make the problem go away when I try to isolate it. I could probably spend another year just doing this. I'm hoping that the collective expertise of Stack Overflow will make this a much more shallow problem or that the cause will be obvious to someone who has more experience than me.

Some facts about my library and the benchmarks:

- The library consists of a front-end API that pushes the log arguments onto a lockless queue (Boost.Lockless) and a back-end thread that performs string formatting and writes the log entries to disk.
- The timing is based on simply calling `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()` at the beginning and end of the program, and printing the difference.
- The benchmark is run on a 4-core Intel CPU (i7-3770K).
- The benchmark program computes a 1024x1024 Mandelbrot fractal and logs statistics about each pixel, i.e. it writes about one million log entries.
- The total running time is about 35 seconds for the single worker-thread case. So the speed increase is about 1.5%.
- The benchmark produces an output file (this is not part of the timed code) that contains the generated Mandelbrot fractal. I have verified that the same output is produced when logging is on and off.
- The benchmark is run 100 times (with all the benchmarked libraries, this takes about 10 hours). The bar chart shows the average time and the error bars show the interquartile range.
- [Source code for the Mandelbrot computation](https://github.com/mattiasflodin/reckless/blob/de548af1f5ea9f716f76b691402b52107ef701e3/benchmarks/mandelbrot.cpp)
- [Source code for the benchmark](https://github.com/mattiasflodin/reckless/blob/de548af1f5ea9f716f76b691402b52107ef701e3/benchmarks/benchmark_mandelbrot.cpp).
- [Root of the code repository and documentation](https://github.com/mattiasflodin/reckless/tree/de548af1f5ea9f716f76b691402b52107ef701e3).

My question is, how can I explain the apparent speed increase when my logging library is enabled?

**Edit**: This was solved after trying the suggestions given in comments. My log object is created on [line 24 of the benchmark test](https://github.com/mattiasflodin/reckless/blob/de548af1f5ea9f716f76b691402b52107ef701e3/benchmarks/benchmark_mandelbrot.cpp#L24). Apparently when LOG_INIT() touches the log object it triggers a page fault that causes some or all pages of the image buffer to be mapped to physical memory. I'm still not sure why this improves the performance by almost half a second; even without the log object, the first thing that happens in the mandelbrot_thread() function is a write to the bottom of the image buffer, which should have a similar effect. But, in any case, clearing the buffer with a memset() before starting the benchmark makes everything more sane. Current benchmarks are [here](https://github.com/mattiasflodin/reckless/blob/master/doc/performance.md)

Other things that I tried are:

- Run it with the oprofile profiler. I was never able to get it to register *any* time in the locks, even after enlarging the job to make it run for about 10 minutes. Almost all the time was in the inner loop of the Mandelbrot computation. But maybe I would be able to interpret them differently now that I know about the page faults. I didn't think to check whether the image write was taking a disproportionate amount of time.
- Removing the locks. This did have a significant effect on performance, but results were still weird and anyway I couldn't do the change in any of the multithreaded variants.
- Compare the generated assembly code. There were differences but the logging build was clearly doing more things. Nothing stood out as being an obvious performance killer.

Comment: First, have you tried profiling the different tests and seeing where the difference might actually be?  That's my first recommendation.  My second is an admitted guess, but it's easy:  `memset()` your `sample_buffer` before you start the timer.  I've seen instances of page faults creating timing issues when first accessing uninitialized memory.

Comment: Normally I'd first suggest looking to a more real-world case when you encounter confusing performance results, but rendering a mandelbrot set is already quite real-worldish so you're good there. I once worked with someone who got all excited when discovering that using `std::vector::insert` made his code seem to consistently go faster than using `std::vector::push_back`, only to then get excited and sporadically apply `insert` everywhere and slowed things down...

Comment: With performance, there's all kinds of dynamic factors that can be involved in causing little performance spikes. One of the most common, as Andrew pointed out, is page faults. Occasionally an optimizer can do weird things when you restructure your code even slightly differently. To get to the bottom of these things, it's always worth having a profiler in your hand and some basic knowledge of how to interpret the disassembly.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that you do have some locks involved in computing the mandelbrot across threads. While I didn't try to break down your logic so much, your logging might actually be slowing down individual threads in a lucky way that reduces contention. When two or more threads try to enter the same critical section, it can be expensive suspending them, so your logger might be slowing things down in a way that just luckily happens to reduce the odds of two threads trying to simultaneously enter the same critical section.

Comment: ... If that is the case, your profiler might show less time spent in the locks with the logging on rather than disabled. You can actually sometimes see a similar case where putting sleep calls in a thread actually improves the throughput because it creates fewer of those lock traffic jams.

Comment: Thanks Andrew and Ike for your input. Over the next couple of days I will experiment with all of the things you have suggested. Regarding the comments about thread contention, please note that the effect is most significant when I have only one worker thread. There should be no contention over the lock in that case. But I will try removing the lock entirely. I did not yet run a profiler for this particular case because I assumed all of the CPU time will be attributed to my one mandelbrot() function, which wouldn't be very helpful. But perhaps I can find some clues in the difference.

Comment: Another remote possibility is just that the optimizer is accidentally doing something weird/beneficial, say with register allocation or instruction selection, with the presence of the logger. One thing that might be helpful is to post the disassembly of the functions with and without the logger. I always forget to do that when I ask performance-related questions since I'm not very good at deciphering it, but doing so has often allowed some assembly experts on this site to really help me understand the behavior better.

Comment: @AndrewHenle you were right on the money with your memset() guess! If you would put it as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution. Thank you both Andrew and Ike for your excellent advice. See more info about the solution in my update.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Another direct reminder for @AndrewHenle to post his answer so it can be accepted and clear this question off the unanswered question queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When uninitialised memory is first accessed, page faults will affect timing.

So, before your first call to, `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()`, initialise the memory by running memset() on your sample_buffer.